# How to handle deleted components in PCB layout

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, layout, via

I am trying to "update" an Altium project; deleting 3 sheets with all components and adding 2 sheets. I completed the schematics and next step is layout.

As I deleted components, I saw so many wires (seems used for previous deleted components but not sure) in different layers and floating vias (there are no names, but not sure if they are used or not, the same for wires).

How can I understand if those vias/wires are used or not, and how can I clean my PCB design from those unused vias/wires simply and effectively?

Comment: Seems counter productive to me, but wouldn't you have to delete the wires connected to the deleted components WHEN you deleted the components.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat In schematic side I deleted all wires and components but in PCB side there still stay vias and wires.

Comment: "there are no names" - and that's exactly the hint for you that they are not used any more. Every wire and via that is still in use has a net name.

Comment: @asdfex Yes it's hint but I need a simple and effective method to detect/select/delete all.

Comment: You can just use the search function (e.g. "find similar") to select all of them.